# Conditional statement bash script

Tags: bash

I need help with replacing the following script with a different format where a configuration file, and a loop is used.

```
    [FedoraC]$ cat script.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    grep -q /tmp /etc/fstab
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "True"
    else
     echo "False"
    fi
    mount | grep  ' /tmp' | grep nodev
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "True"
    else
     echo "False"
    fi

    mount | grep /tmp | grep nosuid
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "True"
    else
     echo "False"
    fi
```

So far I have the following script which should take the values from a source/conf file and run each command found in the conf file one by one. After the command is executed the output would be "True" or "False"

conf file is formed by Unix commands: /opt/conf1

```
    [FedoraC]$ cat conf1 
    grep -q /tmp /etc/fstab
    mount | grep /tmp | grep nodev
    mount | grep /tmp | grep nosuid
    mount | grep /tmp | grep noexec

    [FedoraC]$ cat new_script.sh
    #!/bin/bash
    . conf1
    for i in $@; 
    do $i 
        if [ $i -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Passed"
        else
    echo "Failed"
fi
    done
```

Instead of displaying the output based on the conditional statement, the script runs each line one by one from conf1, and not echo messages are seen.

Can I get some help please.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#! bin/bash
while read L; do
    echo $L'; exit $?'|sh
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo Pass
    else
        echo Failed
    fi
done < conf1
```

Comment: Confirmed solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The more robust and canonical way to do this would be to have a directory `/opt/conf1.d/`, and put each of your lines as an executable script in this directory. You can then do

```
for file in /opt/conf1.d/*
do
  [[ -x $file ]] || continue
  if "$file"
  then
    echo "Passed"
  else
    echo "Failed"
  fi
done
```

This has the advantages of supporting multi-line scripts, or scripts with more complex logic. It also lets you write the check script in any language, and lets scripts and packages add and remove contents easily and non-interactively.

If you really want to stick with your design, you can do it with:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  if ( eval "$line" ) 
  then
    echo "Passed"
  else
    echo "Failed"
  fi
done < /opt/conf1
```

The parentheses in the `if` statement runs eval in a subshell, so that lines can't interfere with each other by setting variables or exiting your entire loop.

Comment: Confirmed solution. Thanks!